# Как назначить текущего юзера к комментарию в Django?

Tags: django

Не могу понять как заасайнить юзера, который создается путем регистрации из коробки джанго, к комменту, который он будет оставлять

Comment: Берите `request.user` и пихайте куда вам надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, что именно не получается.

Просто импортируете User из коробки Django и связываете с ним комментарий через `ForeignKey`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    #other fields...
```

А получать пользователя при создании комментария можно через `request.user`, как и посоветовали в комментариях.